# Global Name Error when deploying with Fabric

Tags: python, django, fabric

The other person on my dev team has been deploying our Django app to the server via Fabric.  Since I need to be able to deploy as well I setup Fabric on my system, but when I try to deploy I get a Global Name error:

```
File ".../fabfile.py", line 4, in staging
  config.settings = 'staging'
NameError: global name 'config' is not defined
```

Since we know the fabfile is fine, it must be a problem in my setup.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your  fabfile? The import lines and the command you are trying to run.  I'd guess that the config is not in your PYTHONPATH, whereas it is on the other dev's.

Comment: No imports. Line 4 is the first line in the first function.  I suspected something similar, but I'm not sure what to add to the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ohhh i know this error , this error is happening because you have installed in your machine fabric version higher than 0.9 and the fabric file that you want to use has been developed using and old version of fabric < 0.9.

For more detail the `config` obj has been replaced with `env` in fabric 0.9 so if you run yor `fabfile` using fabric version higher than 0.9 it will not recognize the `config` object.

so you should install an old version of the fabric package or just update your fabfile i think it's time for that :)

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: @SiweiShen: Yes sorry about that, i guess fabric documentation for old version 0.9 was removed (now they are at 1.4.2) but if you're having the same problem as the OP you should just replace `config` with `env` and check the new doc (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/env.html#the-environment-dictionary-env) if you need to change anything else :)